# Asynchronous wait failed swift API Request

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, xctest

I have created a unit test case for test the function which i handle API requests.

Bellow i have mentioned the XC test case code

```
var expectation:XCTestExpectation?

func testRequestFunction () {

    expectation = self.expectationWithDescription("asynchronous request")

    let test = HVRequest.init(subdomain: "staging", token: "jijfio88fhu0387fh", type: .GET, command: "estm") {
        (success) -> Void in

        }
    test.request()

    self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(30, handler: nil)

}
```

When i run this test case, it gives an error

> Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 30 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "asynchronous request".

How ever it shows the response JSON object with the error.

Please help me to fix the issue

Answer (score 4):

The `XCTestExpectation` is waiting. You have to `fulfill` when you get the respond (mean: say with `expectation` that I get the respond, go ahead).

```
    let test = HVRequest.init(subdomain: "staging", token: "jijfio88fhu0387fh", type: .GET, command: "estm") {
        (success) -> Void in
            expectation.fulfill() // add this line
        }
    test.request()
```

Comment: @anthu i have added which you recommended. after that it says "Exceeded timeout of 30 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations"

Comment: @DimuthLasantha you should add a breakpoint, and see the `fulfill` line is called or not. If not, you should you code, e.g: `HVRequest`